# Is $\{(e^{-x}\cos(\theta), e^{-x}\sin(\theta)): x \geqslant 0, 0 \leqslant \theta \leqslant2\pi\}$ Compact?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

Is $\{(e^{-x}\cos(\theta), e^{-x}\sin(\theta)), x \in \mathbb{R}^{2}: x \geqslant 0, 0 \leqslant \theta \leqslant 2\pi\}$ compact?

**Attempt:**

I've been trying to devlop some sort of visual intuition of what this might look like but I'm not getting anywhere. So to illustrate that the set is compact, I can apply the Heine-Borel theorem. To me it appears as if it is bounded, but I am basing that off of how the individual components of $(e^{-x}\cos(\theta), e^{-x}\sin(\theta))$ behave when $x \geqslant 0$. As far as closed, I have no intuition of how to see if there exists a sequence for every limit point to show that the limit points are also in the set. As a matter of fact, I don't even know what the limit points are of the set.

Some help would be appreciated, more so along the lines of how to approach a situation like this.

Comment: check whether $(0,0)$ is in the set and whether it is an accumulation point.

Comment: Hint: the exponential misses 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not compact: the sequence$$\left(e^{-n}\cos(0),e^{-n}\sin(0)\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}\left(=\left(e^{-n},0\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}\right)$$is a sequence of elements of your set which converges to $(0,0)$, which is outside your set.

Comment: I was just now trying to think of a sequence that converges outside of my set. To make this formal would I have to give an explanation such as you just gave or would more have to be involved to make it sound?

Comment: You could just say that $(0,0)$ doesn't belong to your set. but there are points of your set as close as you wish from $(0,0)$.

Comment: Looking over the solution did you mean $e^{-n}$ ?. Because that makes sense to converge towards $(0,0)$

Comment: Sure! I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @dc3rd of course $e^{-n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$; basic calculus.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, before he edited it the expression had $e^{\frac{-1}{n}}$

Answer (score 2):

Note that your set is exactly the disc with the origin removed, i.e. setting $r=e^{-x}$, we see that $0<r\leq 1$ and your set is 
$$
\{(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta: 0\leq \theta\leq 2\pi, \;0<r\leq 1 \}
$$
the punctured unit disc in polar coordinates, which is bounded, but not closed.